# I have a .shp/.shx file, and I want to make a program that pulls information from these files. Where do i start?

Tags: python, gis, shapefile

An engineering friend needs me to develop a webapp that will read soil types from these .shp/.shx files. Can someone point me in the right direction as to what language I should use? (python?) and also provide me with some helpful links to research?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.shp looks like ShapeFile, So maybe this is what you want: 
https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely look into this.